# Assets\Script\GrabUP.cs(82,38): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public Transform holdPos;
private GameObject heldObj;

void MoveObject()
{   
    heldObj.transform.position = holdPos.transform.rotation;
}
```

I am moving an object behind the camera using the command heldObj.transform.position = holdPos.transform.rotation but the script gives an error

Comment: sry, im edited.

Comment: I retract my close vote. However, you might want to [edit] and further improve according to [answer]. Maybe also take the [tour].

Comment: Think of your code you basically said go to 90 degrees west. You tried to set a position to where its looking. Either set the position or rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to convert rotational values (of type Quaternion )to positional values (Of type Quaternion) maybe try something along the lines of

```
heldObj.transform.position = holdPos.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
```